# Bash Python Library Function - Using Beautiful Soup in shell for HTML-plaintext

Tags: python, html, bash, shell, plaintext

I'm trying to use a bash script in venv to convert a bunch of HTML files in a given directory to plaintext.

Example: **file1.html, file2.html** -> **file1.txt, file2.txt**, where each .txt file is the plaintext from the respective HTML files.

I'm using the Beautiful Soup library (specifically, the **get_text()** function), but am having trouble wrapping my head around how exactly to call the function on each .html file.

The following is what I've been using so far:

```
for i in *; do python -c 'import bs4; print(bs4.BeautifulSoup("'$i'").get_text())' > "$i".txt; done
```

... where $i refers to the current file in the directory as I am iterating one by one.

This currently writes just the filename into the .txt file instead of the Beautiful Soup'd HTML code-into-plaintext:

```
$ cat file.txt
poop.html
```

It also yields the following warning: *"file.html" looks like a filename, not markup. You should probably open this file and pass the filehandle into Beautiful Soup.*

Can anyone lend a hand? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i suggested you should write a seperate python script. Here is how i did that:

beautifulsoup.py file content:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import codecs

if sys.stdout.encoding is None:
    os.putenv("PYTHONIOENCODING", 'UTF-8')
    os.execv(sys.executable, ['python']+sys.argv)

html_file = sys.argv[1]
htmlf = codecs.open(html_file, 'r', encoding='utf-8')
text = BeautifulSoup(htmlf).get_text()
htmlf.close()

print text
```

and call the beautiful.py script like this:

```
for i in *; do python beautifulsoup.py "$i" > "$i".txt; done
```

Answer (score 0):

The BeautifulSoup constructor needs the content of the html file instead of the filename. You have to open the file and pass it to `BeautifulSoup`. Change your line to

```
for i in *; do python -c 'import bs4; with open("'$i'") as f: print(bs4.BeautifulSoup(f).get_text())' > "$i".txt; done
```

Comment: That syntax isn't quite working. I tried modifying it as:

````for i in *; do python -c 'import bs4; f=open('$i'); print(bs4.BeautifulSoup(f.read()).get_text())' > "$i".txt; done````

to no avail. Any ideas?

Comment: @snagglepuss I forgot to add `"` around the filename `$i` inside the call to open. Edited

Comment: It doesn't work with python3 (for some reason it's saying that bs4 can't be imported).

For python:
````for i in *; do python -c 'import bs4; m = open("'$i'"); print(bs4.BeautifulSoup(m).get_text()); m.close()' > "$i".txt; done````

yields the following error:
````'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 78185-78188: ordinal not in range(128)````

Comment: @snagglepuss So your file has characters out of the ascii range.Try to open it with [codecs.open](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#codecs.open) interpreting the file as an unicode file. `import bs4, codecs; m = codecs.open("'$i'", "r", "utf-8"); print(bs4.BeautifulSoup(m).get_text()); m.close()`

Comment: Still no luck :(. Same ascii character range error.

Comment: @snagglepuss Then try adding the argument `errors='ignore'` to the call to `codecs.open`. `import bs4, codecs; m = codecs.open("'$i'", "r", "utf-8", errors='ignore'); print(bs4.BeautifulSoup(m).get_text()); m.close()`.

Comment: I added quotations "" around ignore because otherwise it would complain. After doing that I still got the same ascii error. 

````for i in *; do python -c 'import bs4, codecs; m = codecs.open("'$i'", "r", "utf-8", errors="ignore"); print(bs4.BeautifulSoup(m).get_text()); m.close()' > "$i".txt; done````

Comment: @snagglepuss Besides installing beautifulsoup for python 3 and trying it with this version I'm out of ideas :(

Answer (score 0):

> You should probably open this file and pass the filehandle into Beautiful Soup.

So open the crresponding file and pass the file object to BeautifuSoup constructor.

```
for i in *; do python3 -c 'import bs4;m = open("'$i'"); print(bs4.BeautifulSoup(m).get_text()); m.close()' > "$i".txt; done
```

Answer (score 0):

You should give filehandle as a parameter to BeautifulSoup not filename itself.

```
bs4.BeautifulSoup(open("'$i'")).get_text()
```

Comment: This yielded the same error as halex's revised answer:
````'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 78185-78188: ordinal not in range(128)````

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you put `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` in the first line of your python script.I also suggest that you should probably use python file and call the script with a parameter within the shell command.

Comment: No luck with 
````for i in *.html; do python -c '# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-; import bs4; print(bs4.BeautifulSoup(open("'$i'")).get_text())' > "$i".txt; done
````